# Active Tests window receives __RequestVerificationToken error

Tags: sxa

In a development environment, when I attempt to open the Active Tests window from the Optimizaton tab of the Experience Editor, the window does not finish loading.  I opened Chrome Developer Tools, and see that the following request:

> http://mySite/sitecore/shell/api/ct/Tests/GetActiveTests?page=1&pageSize=75&_=1486004964281

receives an error:

> "{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The required anti-forgery cookie \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","ExceptionType":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"}"

This is on Sitecore 8.1, update 3, with SXA 1.2.

Comment: did you check this [possibility of duplicate issue.] http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2257/sitecore-8-2-experience-analytics-error-anti-forgery-form-field-is-not-present.

Comment: Yes, not a solution. That  issue just concerns error logs, whereas my issue prevents functionality.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue on both 8.1 Update 3 and 8.2 version. I've checked that twice on my local development environment and on our CI. The "Active Test" window opens without issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I"m going to leave this open in calse anyone has an indication where to look.

Comment: @DanSolovay - possibly solved by this: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/search-not-working-for-sitecore-user-field/4160#4160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing an install and a reporting database rebuild on a local development environment, I started receiving the exact same error messages on pretty much any SSC web API call. I evaluated all of the links provided in comments, and the one answer that seemed to help me exactly was the forcible removal and clearing of all cookies for the development domain that I was working on.

The Chrome "Clear Cache and Hard Reset" did not do the trick.

Open up Chrome Tools, Go to Application, and right click on your local site, and press the clear button.  Then refresh your browser.

[image]