# Search not working for Sitecore User Field

Tags: user-profile, account

Using Sitecore 8.0. The template has a field "Author" of field type "Sitecore User". I have created an Item of this template. On clicking *Select*  for "Author", it shows a dialog - "Associate Sitecore User".

Entering text in the search field and clicking on enter, it shows an error in the browser console.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Following this [UPDATE](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/sitecore-6-6-csrf-form-field-is-missing/), I have modified the Sitecore.AntiCsrf.config to:

```
<rule name="shell">
 <urlPrefix>/sitecore/shell</urlPrefix>
  ......
  ......
 <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/*Applications/Security/User*Manager*?*Cart_Users_Callback=yes"/>
 <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/*Applications/Security/Role*Manager*?*Cart_Roles_Callback=yes"/>
 <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/*Applications/Security/Domain*Manager*?*Cart_Domains_Callback=yes"/>
 <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.SelectAccount*Cart_*_Roles_Callback=yes"/>
 <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.SelectAccount*Cart_*_Users_Callback=yes"/>

 <!-- Ingore AntiCSRF completely -->
 <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/*"/>
 </rule>
```

Now, there is no error when searching. But on clicking on OK or Cancel, this error pops up.

[image]

Comment: Look in the Sitecore log for more details about what is failing behind that callback url 500 error.

Comment: The log entry seems to be :                    Exception: Sitecore.Security.AntiCsrf.Exceptions.PotentialCsrfException
Message: CSRF form field is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by:

1. Clear Cookies/Browser cache & try to open in new browser
2. Please add these lines to the Sitecore.AntiCsrf.config file as mentioned under 'xml-controls'
   (website/app_config/include/Sitecore.AntiCsrf.config):

   [image: enter code here]
3. Also add below config into Sitecore.AntiCsrf.config

   ```
   <rule name="shell">
     <!-- Ingore AntiCSRF completely -->
     <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/*"/>
   </rule>
   ```

For more info: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/sitecore-6-6-csrf-form-field-is-missing/

Comment: I included the rules. But clicking on enter or cancel throws an error. I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: i have udpdated the answer for you, it should be under 'xaml-controls'. i have tried to replicate in my local & was able to resolve. Hope you too :)

Comment: That did not work me. The "Failed to load viewstate" error still appears. :(

Comment: Please follow "Clear Cookies/Browser cache & try to open in new browser"

Comment: @Qwerty, were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: No. The issues remains. Its the same error even after clearing cookies and cache

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this config patch:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
      <sitecore>
          <AntiCsrf>
              <rules>
                  <rule name="shell">
                      <ignore contains="/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/ExperienceExplorer.SelectUser.aspx"/>
                  </rule>
              </rules>
          </AntiCsrf>
      </sitecore>
  </configuration>
```